# react input element value type problem in passing value

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsx

maybe dumb question, but

```
// input component shortly
interface InputProps {
// others...
  // valueOf?: InputHTMLAttributes<string>["value"]; // event that lead to the same result
  valueOf?: string;
}

function Input(inputProps: InputProps) {
  const {
    valueOf,
  } = inputProps;

  return (
    
      <input
      //...
        value={valueOf}
      //...
      />
  );
}
export default Input;
```

...and doesn't show any error
and when I try to use it from other component:

```
        <Input
          // ....
          valueOf={'some value'}
          // ...
        />
```

in line of `valueOf={'some value'}` show error

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type '(() => Object) & string'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type '() => Object'.ts(2322)
(property) valueOf: (() => Object) & string
```

tried that
`InputHTMLAttributes<string>["value"]`
and that
`InputHTMLAttributes<string>["value"]; // event that lead to the same result valueOf?: string;`
same

```
const [valueTest, setValueTest] = useState<string>('test');
        <Input
          // ....
          valueOf={valueTest}
          // ...
        />
```

Comment: `valueOf` is a method on the object prototype ([MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf)) it might be your naming that's causing an issue.